# Kinetic.js Use a String to Search for ID

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, kineticjs

EDIT: I want to use a string rectString because I will be using a loop to get all the rectangles and checking to see if any of them have a specific property.

I have a set of rectangles, say their names are 'rect1' , 'rect2' , and 'rect3'. I have been trying to search different ways to search my stage such as:

```
var rectString="rect1";
var method1= stage.get(rectString)[0];
var method2= stage.get(rectString);
var method3 =stage.find(rectString);
var method4=node.getAttr(rectString);
```

and unfortunately none of these work. I am trying to get the stroke color of the shape and then change it using the ID of the shape. 
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will get all the rectangles on the stage into a collection:

```
var allRectangles=stage.find("Rect");
```

Then you can apply a function to each rectangle like this:

```
// run a function for each element in the allRectangles collection

allRectangles.each(function(rect){

    // check if this rect has a red stroke

    if(rect.stroke()=="red"){

        // if the stroke is red, change the stroke to blue

        rect.stroke("blue");

    }

});

layer.draw();
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback but I wasn't very clear in my question. I've edited it now but thanks for your answer!

Comment: I edited my answer to show you how to get all rectangles on the stage and check if any rect has a specific property.